# Application is not recognized by Game Center after building with Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, game-center, xcode6

I was building my game app on Xcode 5.1. The Game Center code is already in place and I've already configured my app through iTunes Connect (such as creating the app entry, setting the bundle identifier, setting up the game center leaderboards).

I got my app working with Game Center successfully when I was in Xcode 5.1. The scores would report to the leaderboards like it should, and I can see my leaderboard entries,etc.

I decided to install Xcode 6.0.1 today. I basically compiled my project with this new version of Xcode. But now when I run my app, I get this from my log:

```
GameKitHelper ERROR: {
NSLocalizedDescription = "The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center.";
```

}

My app is not recognized by Game Center anymore. All is the same. I did not change anything. Just compile and run, and that's it.

Anyone experiencing this problem when compiling and running Game Center enabled apps in Xcode 6.0.1?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Alright I'm able to figure out why. Forgot to mention that I upgraded my test iOS device to 8.0 as well.

It turns out that you need to go to Settings>Game Center and manually enable Sandbox.

I got it working now. Hopefully this helps anyone who face this issue.

Comment: After I had manually enabled Sandbox, I also had to:
->Remove App from device
->Log into Game Center Using the Game Center App

Comment: And what if you are running application o simulator? It's by default in sandbox mode no?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, but with Sandbox already turned on. I've changed the login to the same Apple ID as I use on iCloud and for GameCenter. Now it works again.

I'm using Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4